# Making a 2 digit passcode circuit with a 3*3 matrix keyboard

Tags: digital-logic

I have been trying to make a 2 digit passcode circuit with a predefined code (80) with a maximum of attempts of 3, the code is entered by a 3*3 matrix number keyboard. I'm using the 74HC147 as matrix keyboard encoder, 2 comparators (units and tens) connected to an AND to check if the passcode is right and 3 interconnected D flip flops that count up to the 3 attempts and activate a buzzer once the 3 attempts are completed unsuccessfully. Somehow I'm struggling trying to make the 2 digit passcode part work, I already made it work with dipswitchs but I have to use a keypad, I can't find a way where I can save/storage when you press a number and then another number to compare them after.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to debounce the 3x3 matrix switches, and then latch and shift the result, after converting to binary?

Comment: Yeah! Exactly, saving what two numbers were pressed, hitting another button to send the number to the comparators and checking if the code is right.

Comment: That seems like most of the work, since the earlier part that only needed to perform a comparison between DIP switches and a hard-coded value is very easy. A state machine for debouncing is by itself relatively interesting and much more complicated, already. Then a system to automatically convert to binary and shift into a shift register adds still more. Most of the logic is left to be done, it seems. Have you no thoughts at all about how to engage this? (Start by considering what happens when a key is pressed, including bouncing events. How would you imagine handling this?)

Comment: Actually you are right, I have no idea how to face this. What I thought was using a D flip flop just after the tens comparator, save the logic 1 if 8 was pressed and then connect that D ff to the AND, and I think it would work if I just after ,press 0 and apply the same logic than before.

Comment: Nvm, I just found out that I had a logical lack there and the comparators thing would work since I'm pressing number by number.

Comment: When no key is pressed, things are pretty quiet. When a key is pressed, bouncing starts. Do you have some kind of clock available? If so, what's the rate? If not, you could consider an analog debouncing solution. But that's a whole other thing. You'll need to specify which, clocked or analog, kind of debouncing you are willing to consider. And then things get interesting. We used to have to do this "back in the day" as clean, nice, debounced keyboards were unobtainable, as a rule and we had to do things on our own.

Comment: And, unfortunately, I'm off to bed now.

Comment: Okay. Just a thought about scanning and debouncing. This is from 50 years ago. But it is fairly simple. I used to set up a PNP BJT with an RC tau between its base and emitter, which was tied high (at the time, +5V.) This tends to keep the BJT *off*. But attached to the PNP BJT base were one PNP BJT per column, arranged with simple resistors as collector loads (to ground) and a similar-valued resistor between their base and emitter -- their emitter tied to the base of the first BJT mentioned. The diode-connected keys were arranged with pull-down resistors. This scanned and debounced. Cheaply.